# DeactivateDevice vs. IOCTL_BUS_DEACTIVATE_CHILD

Tags: c++, c, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I am trying to understand the pros and cons of using DeactivateDevice vs. IOCTL_BUS_DEACTIVATE_CHILD, to unload a device driver, in terms of power consumption. If I would like to check the power consumption of the device when the driver was 1)loaded and 2)unloaded, which one would give me the most appropriate value in the latter case? Please suggest and let me know if I am missing any more info needed to answer my question. TIA.

EDIT:
Also, it might be helpful in evaluating the answer for the above question if we know how the above two ways to unload a driver are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. `IOCTL_BUS_ACTIVATE_CHILD` is for bus drivers only (USB, PCI, etc...). upper level client drivers will use `ActivateDeviceEx`.

There is no equivalent wrapper function in the DDK for `IOCTL_BUS_ACTIVATE_CHILD`.

see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2007/04/19/how-bus-drivers-work.aspx

You can also use [SetDevicePower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918190.aspx) to change the power state of a given physical device. (like the WiFi, BT, screen, etc...)

-PaulH

Comment: Thanks PaulH. I was able to use both for the same driver earlier. Hence, I assumed they can be used interchangeably. However, that doesn't seem to be true for all drivers from what you said.

Comment: Also, "if" either can be used for a particular kind of drivers, how would they be different in terms of using resources?